# Main Activity does not create Context

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-context

I need to furnish some `String` content to a new Activity, and I need to do it  when the item on the `RecyclerView` is clicked. My strategy is from the `RecyclerView` I make an interface(instantiating an instance of `MainActivity`) and from the `MainActivity` I launch an explicit `Intent`.
This is my Adapter(so please notice is not the MainActivity):

```
var mainActivity: MainActivity = MainActivity()//because i need to call an interface, please see below

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SimpleViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.bindData(label.get(position).attribute.label.toString())

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(
            View.OnClickListener { view ->
                //val JSONResponseBody = bezinningModels!![position].attribute.body
                val item = label.get(position).attribute.body
                //Log.d("IVO", "item: "+item);
                //val message = editText.text.toString()
                Log.d("IVO", "touched: ");




                mainActivity.injectText(item!!)//an interface launch this, see below


            })
```

the interface is in the same class:

```
public interface LaunchBezinning {
fun injectText(bezinningText: String)
}
```

and in `MainActivity` the compiler launch an error at the line indicated by //error

:

```
class  MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(),LaunchBezinning {

override fun injectText(bezinningText: String) {

    val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity , BezinningContentActivity::class.java)//error

    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, bezinningText)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

I would like to pass to the `BezinningContentActivity` the extra but I get an error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:135)
        at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:130)
        at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:5780)
        at ivano.android.com.bezinning.ui.bezinningList.MainActivity.injectText(MainActivity.kt:14)
        at ivano.android.com.bezinning.ui.bezinningList.BezinningAdapter$onBindViewHolder$1.onClick(BezinningAdapter.kt:70)
```

My guess is that the context is not called, that I should not initialize from the adapter the MainClass. What can I do to pass a String so to open another Activity?

-O-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-

**EDIT:**
as per CommonsWare help I am launching from `onBindViewHolder` this snippet:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(
        View.OnClickListener { view ->
            val intent = Intent(view.context, BezinningContentActivity::class.java)

            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, label.get(position).attribute.body ?: "")
            startActivity(intent)
        })
```

the RecyclerView disappears and an empty `Activity` appears, no errors
but the class is not launched
**two strange things:**

1)**First strange thing** 
startActivity asked me for three parameters instead of one
importing this library(no multiple choices) import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.startActivity

[image: doc startActivity three parameters from Compat v4]

2)**Second Strange thing**
I thought that I had before to declare the context as Commonsware indicated
so I retrieved the `startActivity(intent)//one parameter in this way:

> view.context.startActivity(intent)

Still I get an Activity Empty and I have no idea which Activity is, I put log in Main, and my Activity target and they are not called, I have also added some `<TextView` with some hardcoded text to recognize the activity, but does not work, 
the Activity target is not launched and I do not know how debug an intent, I tried also without success to examine the `Intent` class

EDIT 2:
for mTak

here my adapter class:

```
    internal class BezinningAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleViewHolder>() {
   //    lateinit var context: Context
   // var mainActivity: MainActivity = MainActivity()


    var label = ArrayList<BezinningModel>()


    //it requires minimum these three methods to work

    //returns a ViewHolder for positioning in our view
    //creates new View holder invoked by the layout manager
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SimpleViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.view_recyclerview_row, parent, false)
        //context = view.context
        return SimpleViewHolder(view)
    }


    //giving a position
    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SimpleViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element


        holder.bindData(label.get(position).attribute.label.toString())

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(
                View.OnClickListener { view ->
                    val item = label.get(position).attribute.body
                    val 
      intent=Intent(view.context,BezinningContentActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,item)
    //startActivity(view.context,intent,null)//first one see Edit1
                    view.context.startActivity(intent)//second one passing Context

                    Log.d("IVO", "touched: ");

                    Log.d("IVO", "passed interface in Main: "+intent);




                })

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return label.size
    }

    public fun setTitleData(bezinningModels: List<BezinningModel>) {
        if (bezinningModels == null) {
            return
        }
        label.addAll(bezinningModels)
        notifyDataSetChanged()


    }
    }
```

Comment: Activities are created for you by Android framework. You can't just `var mainActivity: MainActivity = MainActivity()`.

Comment: What does the Edit line mean? Did you try the solution that CommonsWare proposed?

Comment: @mTak really good spotted, I was writing the Edit  linked it with a comment i did on Commonsware answer, but did not work, the EDIT (now complete) explains why.

Comment: @Drocchio can you post the adapter class?

Comment: @mTak Adapter class posted in edit2. ps like your nickname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create a `Context` yourself by means of a constructor, such as the `var mainActivity: MainActivity = MainActivity()`. You get a `Context` from something else. In your case, you have a `View`, and `View` has a Java method named `getContext()`, which you can reference as `context` in Kotlin.

So, replace your existing `OnClickListener` with:

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(
        View.OnClickListener { view ->
            val intent = Intent(view.context, BezinningContentActivity::class.java)

            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, label.get(position).attribute.body ?: "")
            startActivity(intent)
        })
```

(this may require slight modification, as I do not know what `label.get(position).attribute.body` returns, but it should be fairly close)

Comment: your help is really appreciated, unfortunately does not work, if you could please see  the EDIT on the original post I explain why

Comment: (ps `label.get(position).attribute.body`returns a String from the Retrofit Observable)

Comment: First @CommonsWare solution was simpler, and  it works if `onCreate` and 
 the relative `super` of the target activity are modified maintaining only the first parameter. So I am going to accept his reply

Answer (score 1):

Change your adapter's header like this:

```
internal class BezinningAdapter(context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleViewHolder>()
```

now when you initialize it from `MainActivity` you need to pass `this` as a parameter.
Next declare this under the adapter's header:

```
private val parentActivity: MainActivity = context as MainActivity
```

now try your previous code like this:

```
parentActivity.injectText(item!!)
```

I don't know why you use that interface when you could have used just a regular public function in the place of `injectText()`

Comment: Not in the declaration `private lateinit var viewAdapter: BezinningAdapter`. You initialize it somewhere right? There you must pass `getActivity()`.

Comment: you are absolutely right. Sorry if I am wasting your and CommonsWare time.< I deleted the comment because I realized also  that had to declare it not in the declaration but where I create `BezinningAdapter()`>

Comment: I am sorry, I did as you said but does not work, even passing the String in the MainActivity back after I passed the original context instantiating it as you showed me. Plus the intent is so esoteric that I cannot place any log or debug to check, for sure the class target is not called because the log is not triggered

Comment: Then use a regular function of `MainActivity` instead of `injectText()`.

Comment: I start to think that the Context could be messed up because I am using Dagger2 and passed context in Application, basically I tried a simple viable approach to see if a simple explicit Intent would work, and is not! I tried to put in onCreate of the mainActivity a really simple Explicit Intent decommenting the fragment and does not work!!

Comment: issue resolved @mTak, thank you for your help, I accept Commonsware because is the simplest solution. Thank you very much for your help, I learned a lot in this post.